# How do I find what class of anchor tag has using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="signbtn">
    <a class="btnsignin" href="signin.php">Admin</a>
</div>
```

How do I find the class of the anchor tag embedded inside the `div` with `id="signbtn"`.

I need this to be able to assign a different class to the anchor tag only if has `"btnsignin"` class.

Comment: Take a look at find() http://api.jquery.com/find/ and use with attr()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
var class = $('#signbtn a').attr('class');
```

and to assign a different class to an anchor with the `btnsignin` class inside an element with `id="signbtn"`:

```
$('#signbtn a.btnsignin').attr('class', 'some_new_class');
```

Comment: I tried to change the class using the following function, it didn't work, any suggestion? Thank you.  $('#signbtn').click(function() {
  var myclass = $('#signbtn a').attr('class');
  if (myclass == "btnsignout"){
   $('#signbtn a.btnsignout').attr('class', 'btnsignin');
  }
 });

Answer (score 0):

i think should do the trick for you

```
$('#signbtn').click(function() { 
    $.each($(this).children('a'), function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('btnsignin')){
            $(this).attr('class', 'anotherclass');
        }
    })
});
```

also you can change the `$(this).attr('class', 'anotherclass');`
to

```
$(this).addClass('anotherclass');
```

for add multiple classes to the field